How to get IMEI from teltonika FMC003 gps tracker to nodejs server, acknowledge it and get other AVL data?
In the FMCOO3 GPRS settings there is server settings. I've considered that it is my backend server so I have added my nodejs server(domain name) as it is app platform deployed in digitalocean and its port. And set the Protocol TCP  in configurator tool.
Now, I'm not sure how to get the IMEI and AVL datas as in the configurator tool-> status -> GSM Info, socket is closed. The last sent record is : 01/01/1970
const net = require("net");
const logger = require("./helpers/logger");
require("dotenv").config();

const port = process.env.PORT;

// TCP Server for handling Teltonika devices
const tcpServer = net.createServer((socket) => {
  logger.info("TCP Client connected");

  let buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);

  socket.on("data", async (data) => {
    buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);

    // Log received data for debugging
    console.log("Received data:", buffer.toString("hex"));
    logger.info({ buffer }, "Data received from tracker");

    // Handle IMEI processing if buffer is at least 17 bytes
    if (buffer.length >= 17) {
      const imeiProcessed = await handleIMEI(buffer, socket);
      logger.info({ imeiProcessed }, "imeiProcessed is:");
     
    }

    // Handle AVL Data if buffer contains more data
    if (buffer.length > 0) {
      handleAVLData(buffer, socket);
      buffer = Buffer.alloc(0); // Clear buffer after processing
    }
  });

  socket.on("close", () => {
    logger.info("TCP Client disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("error", (err) => {
    logger.error(`Socket error: ${err.message}`);
  });
});

tcpServer.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info("TCP Server is running on port 8080");
});

async function handleIMEI(buffer, socket) {
  const imeiLength = buffer.readUInt16BE(0);
  const imei = buffer.slice(2, 2 + imeiLength).toString("ascii");

  logger.info({ imei }, "Received IMEI:");

  const isAccepted = await validateIMEI(imei); // Implement IMEI validation logic

  if (isAccepted) {
    socket.write(Buffer.from([0x01])); // Send acknowledgment
    logger.info("IMEI accepted and acknowledgment sent");
    return true;
  } else {
    socket.write(Buffer.from([0x00])); // Send rejection
    logger.info("IMEI rejected and rejection sent");
    return false;
  }
}


If your configurator shows Last Record Send 01/01/1970 00:00:00 the device is not even trying to communicate with server. This is probably due to a bad apn or bad parameters for Data Acquisition and GPRS.
Something you can do to test your application is to configure the device to always send data, even without gps fix and time sync on System menu:


Thank you for your reply. Yes, after reading their Universal_Device_Test_Guide documentation, I applied to Always but still server could not communicate. Also, what I could not figure out was why GPRS data sent and data receive traffic was changing.
